# .net on JS call button click event in the backstage

Tags: javascript, .net

The problem is that .Net on JS call button click event did not enter into the background, and the error.

C#

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn" 
    OnClientClick="return dgvCheckhasChoiced();"/> 
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test"  
    CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"/>
```

JS code

```
  if (canDelete) {
        alert(document.getElementById("<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").value);//Here has reutn
        document.getElementById("<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").click();
    //this code is run,but don't int the background 
    //经过此代码却没有进入后台方法点击事件
        msgboxShow('alert','Is Delete？',"alert('123');
        document.getElementById('<%=btnTest.ClientID %>').click();",1,1,'Warning');
        //return alert“123”，Move to next step can't  find the method
        //弹出了提示框“123”，进入到下一步却报找不到该方法
        //return confirm('确认删除？');//To simulate confirm effect 要模拟的confirm效果
        }
        else {
        msgboxShow('BeCareful','Please select at least one need to delete records!','',null,0,'Warning');
        //alert("Please select at least one need to delete records!");
         return false;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Do you perhaps have a coworker or friend with better English skills to who help you?

Comment: @asawyer thanks,I try to use English to ask the question,now,could you  understand

Comment: What exactly is `msgboxShow` ? You appear to have a syntax error here: `msgboxShow('alert','Is Delete？',"alert('123');` - the string for the 3rd parameter is never closed. Is that your problem or is that just a copy/paste mistake? What exactly is the error?

Comment: @asawyer sorry,I don't know this website's code how to write. this is myself write methon msgboxShow('BeCareful','Please select at least one need to delete records!','',null,0,'Warning');                             but there                                            document.getElementById("<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").click();
//this code is run,but don't into the background '

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I can help you.

Comment: @asawyer  I am most grateful to you for your help.I think I should   so hard to learn English.

Comment: I wish I could do more. If you can find someone with a little better English skills, please write a new, better written question.